# Air resistance - smooth vs pimples vs dimples

Tags: drag, aerodynamics

Is there any difference in behaviour between a smooth surface, surface with dimples (dips) and surface with pimples (bumps) when considering aerodynamic drag in a non-rotating frame?

I have a flat platform oscillating slowly (1.5Hz) +/- 20 degrees about the horizontal, in a 10-12 m/s air flow. The closest analogy I can think of is a bicycle pedal (unsurprising, given my avatar...!).

Which surface texture on the underside of the platform will generate the least drag?

Does it make a difference if air flow under the plate is laminar or turbulent?

Comment: This may be a start?  https://waset.org/publications/10000829/vehicle-aerodynamics-drag-reduction-by-surface-dimples

Comment: The paper deals with Dimples vs flat, but makes no mention of Pimples.